# return something other than the object on creation of object

Tags: python, class, object, initialization

I want to make a class that knows to not instantiate based on input parameters. For a simple example if I want to create an object that can only exist if one of its input parameters is > 1 then

```
foo = new_object(0.1)
```

should return `None` to `foo` rather than the object.

Its strikes me as an elegant way to create objects as it means I need no code outside the class to decide whether to create it or not

Is there a way to do this, or equally useful, would this be bad practice, and why?

Comment: Raising `ValueError` would be the Pythonic solution.

Comment: Raising an exception is the usual route, but not the only route.  There are other Pythonic solutions.

Comment: but what if you want to return specific information on why the initialisation failed, can you do this with an exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to override `__new__` -- make sure it takes the same arguments as `__init__`:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __new__(cls, value):
        if value > 1:
            return object.__new__(cls)
        return None
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Test value %d" % self.value


t1 = Test(2)
print repr(t1)
t2 = Test(1)
print repr(t2)
```

Python has support for returning objects of different types from `__new__` but it's a fairly rare practice.

In your use-case, if you are choosing between

```
if value < 1:
    foo = None
else:
    foo = Test(value)
```

and

```
foo = Test(value)  # will None if value <= 1
```

and this is something you have to do many times, then I would definitely consider having the class do it.

In those cases where you don't have control over `new_object` you can make your own factory function:

```
def maybe_foo(value):
    if value > 1:
        return new_object(value)
    return None
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override `__new__()` to effectively turn object instantiation in to a factory-like operation like you want to do here.  I sometimes like to use `__new__()` of an abstract base class as a factory for the concrete subclasses as long as the list of concrete subclasses can be limited and known.  Just make sure it is the best solution for your problem, as it probably isn't...

Answer (score 1):

Quite obviously this would be a bad practice, for the very simple reason that nobody does it like this. Calling a constructor is supposed to construct the object instance, not selectively decide if it wants to or not. You're not supposed to need to check for failure when constructing objects. So it has a quite high "wtf quota", which is never a good idea.

That said, I'm not sure if it's even possible, since `__init__()` is run on the instance after it's already been created (and doesn't end with `return self`). This being Python, I'm sure something can be wrangled. My point is that doing so is a bad idea.

Comment: "that nobody does it like this" makes a practice rare, not necessarily bad.  `__init__` is the initializer, which is only called if `__new__` (the constructor) returns a type that is the same as the class it is a part of.